# How to use isotope images demo but include filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am creating a portfolio website for myself. I'm using the isotope JQuery image demo http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/images.html as the template for the isotope layout on my page, but i want to add the filtering feature which is included from some of the other demo pages. I've tried simply copying what seems to be the options code from the demos that have the filtering option but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are still working on this project, if not, this may help someone else wanting to put images into isotope.  I am still trying to figure out combining multiple filters, but here is how I used one set of filters on my data.  Let's start with the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('#content');

$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
    duration: 350,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false,}
});

    $('#prodnav a').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).attr('prod-filter');
      $container.isotope({ 
      filter: selector,
      animationOptions: {
      duration: 350,
      easing: 'linear',
      queue: false,
   }
 });
   return false;
 });

</script>
```

Here's the navigation list:

```
<div id="prodnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="" prod-filter="*">All Products</a></li>
<li><a href="" prod-filter=".greenwidgetbox">Green Widget</a></li>
<li><a href="" prod-filter=".bluewidgetbox">Blue Widget</a></li>
<li><a href="" prod-filter=".orangewidgetbox">Orange Widget</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And at last, the individual product image code.  I used a thumbnail image for isotope and used shadowbox to maximize the image in a modal window when clicked.

```
<div class="greenwidgetbox">
    <h2 class="box-title">Shiny Green Widget</h2>
      <div class="box-img">
        <a href="images/shiny-green-widget.png" rel="shadowbox" title="Shiny Green Widget"><img src="images/shiny-green-widget-thumb.png"/></a>
       </div>
</div>
```